# What's variant better? SOLID - SRP and interfaces

Tags: java, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

What variant is better? SOLID - SRP or the one with the interface?

```
class Some {
    private final IValidator validator;
    public Some(IValidator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        if (validator.validate(data));
            // do something
    }
}
```

OR

```
class Some {
    private final Validator validator = new Validator();

    public void doSomething() {
        if (validator.validate(data));
            // do something
    }
}
```

Validator is used once.

Comment: Both doesn't compile.. I suppose it's `private final IValidator validator;` and `private final Validator validator`?

Comment: Both compiles succesfully. Do I need interface for Validator class? What  does say SRP principe?

Comment: You should probably worry about how `private final Validator = new Validator();` doesn't work, before thinking about SOLID.. -_-

Comment: oops sorry. I did change question.

Comment: I'd always prefer the interface. This way you can easily switch to a different implementation of the interface later on.

Comment: Title is misleading as this question is not about SOLID. If SRP is Single Responsibility Principle, you already got that covered in S of SOLID.

Comment: If anything, this is more a question about the 'D' of SOLID — Dependency inversion — that Single Responsible principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing `Validator validator = new Validator()` you are actually increasing the coupling of your code, which is definitely against SOLID.

Like @Kris told in the comments, the best way is to use the interface instead of the actual implementation - this actually corresponds more with the polymorphism and already after it it is about SOLID.